# Using QGIS GUI predefined colorramps in Python console / PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, color-ramp

When using the QGIS Gui, there are plenty of predefined colorramps to choose from when styling a layer with e.g. categorized symbology.

[image: QGIS predefined colorramps]

When using the Python console for PyQGIS scripting, [this page of the API docs](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorGradientColorRampV2.html) describes how to create your own colorramp that you can then apply to a renderer object, for example:

```
# create a new colorramp
colorRamp = QgsVectorGradientColorRampV2.create({'color1' : '0,255,0,255',
                                                     'color2' : '255,0,0,255',
                                                     'stops' : '0.5;255,255,0,255'})

# set up an empty categorized renderer and assign the colorramp
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(field, [])
renderer.setSourceColorRamp(colorRamp)
```

Is there a way to access the predefined colorramps that are accessible from the GUI and assign them to a renderer instead of creating my own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general you should look at this [page](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorColorRampV2.html) of the APIs documentation. As a working example see as follows:

```
vl = iface.activeLayer()
## get default style
myStyle = QgsStyleV2().defaultStyle()
## get a list of default color ramps [u'Blues', u'BrBG', u'BuGn'....]
defaultColorRampNames = myStyle.colorRampNames()
## setting ramp to Blues, first index of defaultColorRampNames
ramp = myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[0])
# set up an empty categorized renderer and assign the color ramp
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(field, [])
renderer.setSourceColorRamp(ramp)
vl.setRendererV2(renderer)
```